# Concatenation in javascript - Taking words from array and putting them in new string

Tags: javascript, string

Take the first line. I want to get all the "words" between ** and put them into one new string.

```js
var str = "John Smith The vladimir *G3* asterix *rocket* ";
var re = /\s/g;
var splitter = str.split(re); // Splitting words and putting them in array


var note = ""; // Empty string to be concatinated
console.log(note);
for (var i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {

  var bold = /\*\w+\W+/;
  if (! (splitter[i].search(bold))) {
    console.log("this is the bold text: " + splitter[i]); // *G3*, *rocket*
    bolded = splitter[i];

    note.concat(bolded, " ");
  }
  // else

}
```

We can see that I have empty string waiting to be populated and when i loop through the words in my first string, i do get all items that are wrapped around stars **. But somehow i cant concatenate them into new one:

var note = "";

And after note is populated, i want to console log it to see the results.

Comment: you never define `bolded` before you try to assign it within the `if-statement`

Comment: `concat` is an array operation. Your `note` variable is a `String`. String concatenation is done with `+`. So you could change `note.concat(...)` to `note += " " + bolded;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert but is this what you're looking for?

```
var str = "John Smith The vladimir *G3* asterix *rocket* ";
var re = /\s/g;
var splitter = str.split(re); // Splitting words and putting them in array


var note = []; // Empty array for words
console.log(note);
for (var i = 0; i < splitter.length; i++) {

  var bold = /\*\w+\W+/;
  if (! (splitter[i].search(bold))) {
    console.log("this is the bold text: " + splitter[i]); // *G3*, *rocket*
    bolded = splitter[i];

    note.push(bolded);
  }
  // else

}

var my_string = note.join(" ")
console.log(my_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

`note.concat(bolded, " ");`

The .concat method return te result of union bewteen `note` and the new founded word `bolded`.

You have to put from this way:

`note = note.concat(bolded, " ");`

For more clarification see: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat